# revived closed tab in chrome doesn't work properly, but works correctly in IE and Firefox

Tags: cross-browser, google-chrome

I'm working on a website where information is loaded from a calendar. If a user clicks on a link on the calendar, it displays information about that link. If I close that page, and then re-open it, it works properly on both IE and Firefox, but if I open it in chrome, and click on another item on the calendar it instead errors out.

Is there a large difference in how chrome brings back tabs from how IE or Firefox do that would cause this?